# How many stacks are needed for converting the below infix expression to postfix expression?

Tags: data-structures, stack

If the expression is `E = A + B`, where `A = log(3x+4)`, `B = log(log(3x+4)+5)`, and I want to define a postfix expression for it, so how many stacks are required for this?

I'm not able to approach it because of these logarithmic terms, so please clarify this?

Comment: One stack regardless the complexity of the expression. You should copy each constant or variable in the output, and use stack to implementation of an operator priority.

Comment: But what about the logarithmic terms involved in it .

Comment: I wrote you detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be solved using Dijkstra's [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). A single stack is enough. Logarithmic functions can be solved as any other function. The precedence is in order `() > log > * > +`. Given `E = A + B`, supplying the values we'd have:
`E = log(3*x + 4) + log(log(3*x + 4) +5)`.
Considering `3x` as `3*x` and scanning from left to right and applying the Shunting algorithm step by step, the Postfix expression will be:

```
3 x * 4 + log 3 x * 4 + 5 + log log +
```

I used single space to delimit operators and operands for readability. A few key points from Shunting Yard Algorithm that would help you solve this and similar questions are:

1. The postfix expression does not contain any parentheses.
2. The operators maintain their order in both prefix and postfix expressions.
3. Operators with lower precedence are at lower below the operators with higher precedence in stack. If a higher precedence operator is at the top of the stack and a lower precedence symbol is being scanned, then all operators with higher precedence are popped out of stack and written in output and lower precedence operator is pushed in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The single stack enough.

For example let examine a few simple expressions:

`a + b * 1` gives `a b 1 * +`

`a * b + 1` gives `a b * 1 +`

As you can see, we can simple copy each constant or variable from an input stream to an output, but we should process operators. Let's use the operators' stack. For each operator from an input stream we can store it to the stack, or we can copy it to an output stream.

To make a decision we should compare a precedence of the operator on the top of the stack, and a precedence of the next operator from the input stream.

For `* > +` (as in the first example above) you need to push the next operator `*` to the stack. Also you need to push the first operator to the stack.

For `+ <= *` (as in the second example) you need to copy the operator to the output stream.

At the end of the input stream you need to pop all remaining operators from the stack and copy them to the output stream.

*Expressions with parentheses:* just consider `(` as operator with a highest precedence. Copy it to the stack. With the `)` do pop operators from the stack till the `(` and put them to the output. Then pop `(` but don't put `(` and `)` symbols.

`a * (b + c * d)` gives:

1. `a` — `*`
2. `a b` — `* ( +`
3. `a b c` — `* ( + *`
4. `a b c d * +` — `*`
5. `a b c d * + *`

*Functions:* `3 * log(x + 2)` is `x 2 + log 3 *` in the postfix form, so you just can consider the precedence of `() > log > *`.

Now **important note**: you need the one stack to output an expression in postfix form. But you need two stacks to evaluate the same expression — first to variables/constants, and second to operators.

Answer (score 0):

PostFix expression of that would be :

```
E 3 x * 4 + log 3 x * 4 + log 5 + log + =
```

Going from left to right if you come across operator then you simply put it in between the two operands that are in front of it. for example 2 3 + => 2 + 3 except for log in case of log it would be something like this 2 3 log => 2 log(3) if there is a situation like this 2 3 log + then => 2 log(3) + => 2 + log(3) Enjoy the following steps

```
step 1: E, (3*x), 4, +, log, 3, x, *, 4, +, log, 5, +, log, +,=
note **,** is just for the separations you can ignore if you want  
step 2: E, (3x + 4 ), log, 3, x, *, 4, +, log, 5, +, log, +, = 
step 3: E, log(3x + 4), 3, x, *, 4, +, log, 5, +, log, +, =
step 4: E, log(3x + 4), (3*x), 4, +, log, 5, +, log, +, =
step 5: E, log(3x + 4), (3x + 4), log, 5, +, log, +, =
step 6: E, log(3x + 4), log(3x + 4), 5, +, log, +, =
step 7: E, log(3x + 4), (log(3x +4) + 5 ), log, +, =
step 8: E, log(3x + 4), log(log(3x + 4) + 5), +, =
step 9: E, log(3x + 4) + log(log(3x+ 4) + 5), =
step 10: E = log(3x + 4) + log(log(3x+4) + 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

A stack is needed to solve the given expression

```
E = A + B, where A = log(3x+4), B = log(log(3x+4)+5)
```

regardless of the fact that it seems too complex. You can also plug in the equivalent expressions of A and B in expression E and then solve the entire expression E as a single expression.

Therefore, after solving, the equivalent postfix expression will be:

```
3x*4+log3x*4+log5+log+
```